# How to remove formula from cell and replace with number in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Say I've got a cell, C1. The formula in C1 is =A1*B1, which equals 2. How do I remove the formula and replace it with just the resulting number after it's been calculated? I've tried this:

```
Dim x As Long

x = .Range("C1").Value
.Range("C1").Value = x
```

This does not work, because x attempts to store the formula, not the calculation of said formula.

Comment: `x` will *not* contain the formula with that code. For starters, a `Long` can't contain **text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the result of the calculation just use

```
With .Range("C1")
    .Value2 = .Value2
End With
```

If you want the formula use `.Formula`